# Solution for encoding $.ajax posts without JSON?

Tags: jquery

I've been doing some research to find a solution to use $.ajax with JSON that can handle character encoding issues. Looking through past posts I've seen notes about contentType and other suggestions I've incorporated.

Long story short, an entry like "Bobs Resume" works in vanity_name, but "Bob's Resume" doesn't.

Wondering if there is something else I'm missing?

```
var myData = { 
    resume_id : '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('resume_id'); ?>',                 
    vanity_name: $('#vanity_name').val()
} 

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '<?php echo site_url('resume/change_vanity_name'); ?>',
    contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-1",
    data: myData,
    dataType: "html",
    success : function(msg){                    
            $('#vanity_name_session').text($('#vanity_name').val());
            },
    error: function(){
               alert('failure');
        }
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encodeURIComponent should do the trick. -

EDITED correct answer

use

```
var nv = encodeURIComponent($('#vanity_name').val());
var myData = { 
    resume_id : '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('resume_id'); ?>',                 
    vanity_name: vn
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Drew  No luck -- I had to remove the ; to get it work, but it still won't accept any special characters.

Comment: ahhh my bad - try making the vanity_name variable ouside of the data so var vn = encodeURIComponent($('#vanity_name').val()); then call vn in your data...

Comment: Thanks, you were correct. Sorry about that. Part of the issue was actually dealing with the input of the special characters.

Comment: sorry about the initial confusion :) glad you got it!